# why we need hadoop for hypertable

Tags: hadoop, hbase, hypertable

i have written an crawler in c++ and i am looking for an distributed data store i found 2 
1) hbase
2) hypertable

both are the implementation of Big table and i just reviewed hypertable.. because it was implemented in c++ and..hbase is most widely used 
my question is way we need hadoop...is there is any benifits if i run hypertable on top of hadoop?

Comment: i think your main question is:
 In terms of performance where hypertable function better(on plain file system or on hadoop)?

Answer (score 4):

It's not required to use Hadoop. Hypertable only requires to be ran on top of distributed filesystem. So, you can choose between Hadoop DFS, KosmosFS, GlusterFS, Ceph, and maybe some others (like MooseFS or Lustre).

Common benefits are determined by application requirements and existent infrastructure. From a troubleshooting point of view, community (especially Hadoop's) size is also the great factor.

Comment: HyperTable can also run on plain local file system.

Comment: In terms of performance where hypertable function better(on plain file system or on hadoop)?

Answer (score 0):

You can also look into cassandra (http://cassandra.apache.org/) another implementation somewhat similar to Big Table.